# String was not recognized as a valid DateTime from DateTimePicker

Tags: c#, datetime, datetimepicker, datetime-parsing

I get his error at `hnddate`(hidden field value coming from date time picker):

> String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.when converting a string to datetime parse the string to take the date before putting each variable

```
DateTime weekStartDate = GetFirstDayOfWeek(Convert.ToDateTime(hdndate.Value))
                                          .AddDays(0);
DateTime weekEndDate = weekStartDate.AddDays(14);
```

the query gets the startdate by comparing to a column in datatabse which is in 2014/04/28 and the datepicker (hnddate) has 28/04/2014 format.

Comment: the query gets the startdate by comparing to a column in datatabse which is in 2014/04/28 and the datepicker (hnddate) has 28/04/2014 format.

Comment: `Convert.ToDateTime()` takes a string, but a datepicker's `Value` is already a DateTime object, not a string.

Comment: datetime picker is of jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `hdndate.Value` is actually a string and its value is `"28/04/2014"`:

Replace this:

```
Convert.ToDateTime(hdndate.Value)
```

With this:

```
DateTime.ParseExact(hdndate.Value, "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

---

[`DateTime.ParseExact`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) allows you to specify the exact format of your input string, so that it can correctly generate a `DateTime` from it. In this case, your format is `dd/MM/yyyy`.